# Экранировать спецсимволы внутри регулярного выражения

Tags: php

Есть задача, выполнить вот такой реплейс:

```
$settings['main_categories_separator'] = '/'; // но тут могут быть разные разделители: / , . * & \ |
$value['main_category'] = 'Фонари/Фонари Наключные';
$value['main_category'] = preg_replace('/^'.$settings['main_categories_separator'].'/iu', '', $value['main_category']);
```

Подскажите как можно сделать, что бы спецсимволы из переменной **$settings['main_categories_separator']** экранировались автоматически, а не были частью регулярки.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-quote.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

preg_quote — Экранирует символы в регулярных выражениях

```
$value['main_category'] = preg_replace('/^'.preg_quote($settings['main_categories_separator'], "/").'/iu', '', $value['main_category']);
```